# How to format a column which contains dates

Tags: r

I am new to R.
How to format a column which contains over 1000 records of dates(this is the format i am looking for 2016-01-05, 2016-04-12).
After importing the excel file in to R, above dates have changed to 16896 16903 and so on, what is the best way to format it.

Comment: Sounds like your dates started in unix time, starting 1970-01-01.

Comment: how are you importing the file? have you tried specifying the column type while importing the data into R ? look into `readxl()` and `column_type`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
date <- ymd("2016-01-05")
```

this will do the trick for you. change the date with you column name